# Is there a way to make a file ordered first in the typescript build

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to order a single typescript file first in the visual studio built-in typescript build?  I named the file "_default.ts" and this works most of the time, but not 100% of the time.  My goal is to get my jsHint line of code near the top of the Bundle.js file.

Comment: The order could by foreced by `/// <reference>`. I know that there are 2 options how to do it. First is that you need to specify reference to first file in every other file... second is that you have one extra file which define references to all other files including first file and references are ordered there as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `tsconfig.json`, you can explicitly list the `"files"` field. This works best for clean and linear dependencies. For example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "none",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "files": [
        "file1.ts",
        "file2.ts"
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, [like Misaz said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641342/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-file-ordered-first-in-the-typescript-build#comment78247291_45641342), each of your files can have an explicit `/// <reference path="..." />` comment to indicate its dependencies.

However, if you decide to create one file that references all of your source code with `/// <reference path="" />` comments, you might as well use `tsconfig.json`'s `files` option.

Comment: In my case, it is easier to just make a small edit in VS and then undo the edit on the file I want to appear first.  This will rebuild the Bundle.js with the file I just edited at the top.  However, your answer works for those that have enough time to create these configuration files.